# How to select random row with count()

Tags: mysql, group-by, order-by, count, random

Table names:

```
g_number  name
123       John
123       Sara
123       Michael
```

I want to get one RANDOM name and quantity of all names with the same g_number in one query:

```
SELECT name, count(*) cnt
FROM names
WHERE g_number='123'
ORDER BY rand()
```

But result is always the same

```
name    cnt
John    3
```

Looks like count() ignores ORDER BY rand() line.
So that's the question: is it possible to solve this in ONE query?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you want to do two different things in one query:

1. *randomly choose one* `name` out of all the ones `WHERE g_number=123
2. count *all* the rows `WHERE g_number=123`.

If that's what you want to do, do it with **two** subqueries:

```
SELECT
   (
     SELECT name
     FROM t
     WHERE g_number = 123
     ORDER BY rand()
     LIMIT 1
   ) AS name
   , (
     SELECT count(*)
     FROM t
     WHERE g_number = 123
   ) AS count_of_123
```

That will give you as a result:

```
|    name | count_of_123 |
|---------|--------------|
|    Sara |            3 |
```

or

```
|    name | count_of_123 |
|---------|--------------|
| Michael |            3 |
```

or

```
|    name | count_of_123 |
|---------|--------------|
|    John |            3 |
```

You can check it at http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/5342d2/8/0

This is not just MySQL, it is standard SQL (except, maybe, for the name of the `rand()` function, that might be DBMS-dependent). The query also reflects clearly the fact that you want to do two (related but different) things. You can check also at SQLFiddle the [PostgreSQL version](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!15/85256/3/0), and the [SQLite](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!5/85256/1/0) one.

---

Within the realm of MySQL, you can use one non-standard query that will also work (and which, performance-wise, is *probably* better):

```
SELECT
   name, count(*) AS count_of_123
FROM
   (
     SELECT name
     FROM t
     WHERE g_number = 123
     ORDER BY rand()
   ) AS q0 ;
```

I think this is closer to what the original poster had in mind. Even so, *I wouldn't* rely on it. This is *very far from* standard SQL. MySQL *might* decide to change how this is implementd and behaves in the future. Also, IMHO, it is *less clear* what the intent of the query is.

Check it at http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/5342d2/10/0

Comment: Yes! I also think about last variant! but stuck on - is it One query or Two :)

Comment: Your last MySQL variant has the same problem as mine: it always returns the same name. The first proposed combination does the job. But i can't understand why MySQL (not yours, not mine) variant doesn't work???

Comment: Last variant, checked at SQLFiddle doesn't always produce the same value.

Comment: Press `Run SQL` at least ten times... not just 2 or 3.

Comment: MySQL v5.7.11, I've clicked 20 times: result is 100% 'John', '3'

Comment: I want to understand why MySQL decides to return only 'John'.

Comment: I can confirm that the mySQL version used by rexTester (5.7.12) behaves the same way as yours (and different from the two available at SQLFiddle). Check it http://rextester.com/VLYV68023. See the execution plans for the two example queries at the bottom. MySQL 5.7.12 is *too smart*, and decides that the `ORDER BY` of `q0` isn't needed if you're going to aggregate the result, and the effect on `RAND()` disappears. One more reason **not to rely** on very non-standard behaviours. They change from version to version. Hope this helps.

Comment: provided solution returns unexpected 'null', '0' when there is no such g_number, so based on your answer this is a solution:
 SELECT * FROM
( SELECT
   (
     SELECT name
     FROM ns
     WHERE g_number = 123
     ORDER BY rand()
     LIMIT 1
   ) AS name
   , (
     SELECT count(*)
     FROM ns
     WHERE g_number = 123
   ) AS cnt
) a
WHERE a.cnt > 0

Comment: That's the expected behavior

Answer (score 1):

Another way...

```
SELECT  SUBSTRING_INDEX(GROUP_CONCAT(name ORDER BY RAND()),
                       ',', 1)  AS random_name,
        COUNT(*) AS ct
    FROM names
    WHERE g_number='123';
```

(It assumes that there are no commas in `name`.)

Comment: nice trick, but names here are just as example. in real tables may be any possible symbol.

Comment: @Igor - I will grant you that this is not perfect.  "tab" is usually a safe character.  There is a default limit of 1024 bytes on the result of `GROUP_CONCAT`, but that can be raised.  `BLOBs` are likely to have every possible byte value, so it can't work there.  Etc.  `UNHEX(substring... HEX(name) ...,` avoids _some_ of the pitfalls.